# ABS+SlideMenu - Best way to load fragments from drawer

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock

How the facebook or google plus app works with `SlideMenu` !!
I have a project using `ABS+SlideMenu` and I will need to show different layouts with different buttons, images etc in a `Fragment`.

So basically I have 2 `Fragments`

1) Slide Menu - `ListView` items

2) Content Page - `Relative Layout`

So simply I just need to show dynamic fragments on Content Page upon selecting them from `SlideMenu`. What is the best way to do it ?

Answer (score 0):

You can find a very good implementation of this pattern here....

https://github.com/jfeinstein10/SlidingMenu

Also works with ABS. Comes with good examples - all of which are nicely bundled up into a demo app on google play...

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.slidingmenu.example&feature=search_result#?t=W251bGwsMSwxLDEsImNvbS5zbGlkaW5nbWVudS5leGFtcGxlIl0.